# wp_editor not saving data, and text area showing html tags

Tags: custom-field, wp-editor

This is my custom meta box, here text area showing html tags.i used tinymc textaea editor. and i try to use wp_editor also. but data not saving.if it saved, i don't know how to call it.
please help me find solution --THANK YOU--

```
<?php
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
    add_action('save_post', 'save_points');
    function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box("productInfo-meta", "Product Details", "product_meta_options", "product", "normal", "low");}

    function product_meta_options(){
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $category = $custom["category"][0];
        $brand = $custom["brand"][0];
        $features = $custom["features"][0];
        $holds = $custom["holds"][0];
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Category
        <td> <input type="text" size="100" name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brand
        <td> <input type="text" size="100" name="brand" value="<?php echo $brand; ?>" /> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Features</td>
        <td><textarea rows="20" cols="100" name="features"><?php echo $features; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <?php wp_editor( $content, 'test_content', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'test_content','textarea_rows'=>20) );?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Holds
        <td><textarea rows="20" cols="100" name="holds"><?php echo $holds; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
}

function save_points(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "category", $_POST["category"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "brand", $_POST["brand"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "features", $_POST["features"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "holds", $_POST["holds"]);
}?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things going wrong in your code. I had to install it to see them all.

**First**, You don't want `global $post`. [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) will pass the post ID. Add a parameter to your callback.

```
function save_points($post_id){
    update_post_meta($post_id, "category", $_POST["category"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "brand", $_POST["brand"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "features", $_POST["features"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "holds", $_POST["holds"]);
}
```

Note: that only passes the post ID, not the whole post object. If you needed the whole object (which you don't) you could request a second parameter.

**Second**, lines like this one-- `$brand = $custom["brand"][0];`-- are triggering notices. You should be checking for the key before trying to use it.

```
$brand = (!empty($custom["brand"][0]) ? $custom["brand"][0] : '';
```

**Third**, that solves potential problems with lines like this one-- `<td><textarea rows="20" cols="100" name="features"><?php echo $features; ?>`-- by setting the value that are `echo`ing to something.

**Fourth**, you have a number of unclosed `<td>` tags causing very broken markup.

**Fifth**, `wp_editor`, possibly the default instance, does not seem to like manually created `textarea`s. I don't know of a workaround but maybe there is one. I would love to know if someone out there has a solution. In the meantime, using `wp_editor` for all of the `textarea`s seems to work.

**Sixth**, see this answer for issues with doing what you are doing if using less than (it looks to me) WordPress 3.5.

**Seventh**, saving the keys as you are you going to have your meta fields show up in the default meta fields box as well. Save your fields with a leading underscore.

**Eight**, you weren't saving your content from the `wp_editor` in your original code at all.

**Nine**, you weren't retrieving you post content either.

**Ten**, you are running this code for all post saves, not just for your custom post type.

**Eleven,** you probably want to check that you are not dealing with a post revision, as in [this example from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Example).

**Twelve**, you would really do well to [sanitize your `POST` data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) before shoving it into the database. `POST` data ***is not safe***. Though you can't see it in the URL is *trivial* to alter.

Put that all together, except for the data validation which I will leave to you since this is a marathon answer already :

```
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
add_action('save_post', 'save_points', 1, 2);
function admin_init(){
  add_meta_box("productInfo-meta", "Product Details", "product_meta_options", 'product', "normal", "low");
}

function product_meta_options(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $category = (!empty($custom["_category"][0])) ? $custom["_category"][0] : '';
  $brand = (!empty($custom["_brand"][0])) ? $custom["_brand"][0]  : '';
  $features = (!empty($custom["_features"][0])) ? $custom["_features"][0]  : '';
  $holds = (!empty($custom["_holds"][0])) ? $custom["_holds"][0]  : '';
  $content = (!empty($custom["_custom_content"][0])) ? $custom["_custom_content"][0]  : '';
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Category
        <td> <input type="text" size="100" name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brand
        <td> <input type="text" size="100" name="brand" value="<?php echo $brand; ?>" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Features</td>
        <td><?php wp_editor( $features, 'features', $settings = array('textarea_rows'=>20) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>
        <?php wp_editor( $content, 'custom_content', $settings = array('textarea_rows'=>20) );?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Holds</td>
        <td><?php wp_editor( $holds, 'holds', $settings = array('textarea_rows'=>20) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
}

function save_points($postid,$post){
  global $_POST;
  // set the ID to the parent post, not the revision
  $postid = (wp_is_post_revision( $postid )) ? wp_is_post_revision( $post ) : $postid;
  $post_type = get_post_type( $postid );
  if ('product' == $post_type) {
    update_post_meta($postid, "_category", $_POST["category"]);
    update_post_meta($postid, "_brand", $_POST["brand"]);
    update_post_meta($postid, "_features", $_POST["features"]);
    update_post_meta($postid, "_holds", $_POST["holds"]);
    update_post_meta($postid, "_custom_content", $_POST["custom_content"]); // save the data
  }
}
```

Comment: @s_ha_dum...thank you for your answer.I just need to know why this editor field not saving data and how can i call back this content....

?php wp_editor( $content, 'test_content', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'test_content','textarea_rows'=>20) );?>

Comment: thank you  s_ha_dum. http://pastebin.com/DpJAUufP this is my code before you fix the errors. now i just want to know how print the code in my page.

Comment: Sorry? How to print what code?

Comment: how can i  show the field content in my page?. i mean how can i  call the field content. <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'brand', true ) ); ?> is it correct ?.

Comment: On the front end? `echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_brand', true ) );` Note the leading underscore.